# Excluding specific posts from Wordpress search results in sync with found_posts

Tags: wordpress, loops, filter

I have a search results page which simply displays a list of wordpress page URL's. I want to exclude specific page URL's from appearing in this list. The list looks something like this: ( The total count is taken from ->found_post ).

**Page Results (10 in total):**

- http://example.com/bill
- http://example.com/cheese
- http://example.com/moo

To make sure my found_posts total was correct, I thought I'd make a global filter like this and place it in functions.php :

```
function search_filter( $query ) {

    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        $exclude = array(
            16,
            261,
            260
        );
        $query->set( 'post__not_in', $exclude );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_filter' );
```

this would work fine if it wasn't for the fact that *the search results page is one I don't want to appear in the search results.* Adding this to the exclude array results in the search results page itself 404'ing.

So I thought then I could just put a check in the actual template loop like so:

```
if(!in_array(get_the_ID(), $exclude)):
```

but then my `found_posts` count is wrong, it counts the post but doesn't show it.

Is there a way to exclude the post, from the displayed results, and also reflect this in the found_posts count?

Comment: just decrease found posts when removing a item or write a custom wp_query specifying post__not_in

Comment: I never realised its possible to externally change found_posts. I'll check it out.

Comment: Thanks David, your comment is the answer. If you did want to add it I'll check it off, otherwise I'll just leave it open.

Comment: ah it wasnt really an answer, you can answer yourself if you like!